# placeholder is not working in mui phone number in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am creating a mui phone number .but initial if you not provide any value in phone number then placeholder should shown but if you type any value then this placeholder should hide, how to create this place holder

```
import React from "react";
import MuiPhoneNumber from "material-ui-phone-number";
export default function App() {
  const [fields, setFields] = React.useState([{ value: null }]);
  function handleChange(i, event) {
    if (event) {
      let values = [...fields];
      values[i].value = event;
      setFields((v) => values);
    }
  }
  return (
    <>
      {fields.map((fields, idx) => (
        <MuiPhoneNumber
          defaultCountry={"us"}
          placeholder="Entre phone number"
          onChange={(e) => handleChange(idx, e)}
        />
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Label instead of placeholder as you are using mui-phone-number.

```
    <MuiPhoneNumber
      defaultCountry={"us"}
      label"Entre phone number"
      onChange={(e) => handleChange(idx, e)}
    />
```